# How to properly combine selectors with JavaScript identifiers?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have selected a DOM element in JavaScript.

```
var myParentElement = document.getElementById('myParentId');
```

Now, let's say I want, using jQuery to select the first element which is a child of that one, is a visible, enabled input element, AND has a specific value for a given attribute (here and I want to check the element's *name*).

```
$([name="myChildName"]).children(':input:enabled:visible:first'); // ?
```

The above snippet is incorrect, how should I fix it? (I know a bit of CSS but not much jQuery).

Additional requirement: I am limited to jQuery 1.7.2

EDIT : sorry, actually was a tiny bit more complicated than the first line, as I have a name, not an ID.

Anyway, thanks to your advice I have found the solution I was looking for:
$("[name=' + myNameIdentifier +']").filter(":input:enabled:visible:first");
IIRC **the first pair of quotes is a must** and not including them was a blatant error.

Additionally, I neglected the difference between children, find and filter so my question was unclear. I wanted to select all elements with a given name, then apply a filter on that selection (do not care about children or descendants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [children selector(`>`)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('#myParentId > [name="myChildName"]:input:enabled:visible:first')
```

Comment: I did not think about that, altough it was so obvious :(

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

$.children() returns all of the children elements of an element, so your code actually tries to find `:input:enabled:visible:first` **inside** the `[name="myChildName"]` element, and not just filter it. you probably want to:

```
$('#myParentId').children(':first-child:enabled:visible')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I do not quite understand however, shouldn't $([name="myChildName"]) give me a list of elements, and not a single one ? (afaik, name, unlike id, is not required to be unique in a document).
Also, regarding your proposed code, isn't .children jQuery specific ? myParentElement is not selected the jQuery way, so it is a regular HTMLElement. They do not allow using jQuery's .children(), do they ?

Comment: 1. `$([name="myChildName"])` indeed returns a list. But, `.children()` doesn't mean "all members of a list...", it means: "children elements of a given element(s)"

2. You are right, I've just fixed my code so that it works with jquery to begin with, and not with the regular HTMLElement object.